# How to draw equal horizontal lines between one button to another in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Here I am trying to draw a horizontal line between the buttons. I have tried in many ways but I can't get it. I think I need to do some magics in CSS but I am new to HTML and CSS That's why I can't find the way to make it work.

I want:

[image]

I got this:

[image]

```css
.divided {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.divider {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="container" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
      <div class="row divided">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button mat-mini-fab>1</button>
            <span style="padding-left:15px">Login</span>
        </div>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button mat-mini-fab>2</button>
            <span style="padding-left:15px">Address</span>
        </div>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button mat-mini-fab>3</button>
            <span style="padding-left:15px">Mycart</span>
        </div>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button mat-mini-fab>4</button>
            <span style="padding-left:15px">Payment</span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: use the after psuedo class

Comment: Brother ,I am new to CSS and HTML I could not understand "after psuedo class" @charankumar

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: version 4 @לבנימלכה

Comment: check pseudo class reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: You can imbricate flexbox (use CSS or built-in class), remove the divider and use a pseudo instead and drop the column class. from there you can draw those lines with a classic flex method: example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aabOYP

Answer (score 2):

Use [pseudo `:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to `<div class="col-sm-3 divder">`

Instead using  `<span class="divider"></span>` (-- remove it)

```css
.divder:after{
    content: '';
    width: 71px;
    height: 2px;
    top: 15px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
        <div class="col-sm-12 row">
        <div class="container" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
          <div class="row divided">


              <div class="col-sm-3 divder">
                  <button mat-mini-fab>1</button>
                  <span style="padding-left:15px">Login</span>
              </div>            
              <div class="col-sm-3 divder">
                  <button mat-mini-fab>2</button>
                  <span style="padding-left:15px">Address</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 divder">
                  <button mat-mini-fab>3</button>
                  <span style="padding-left:15px">Mycart</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <button mat-mini-fab>4</button>
                  <span style="padding-left:15px">Payment</span>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please see the updated image ,I got the above response after applying your solution.I want to have the horizontal line from the END of text to BUttON .Ex: end of the login text to Address Button. please help me to fix it

Comment: just "play" with css to move it (maybe remove padding/margin from `col-sm-3`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do the same as you would do when using a stepper

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Using import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
and the correct elements will do the trick

Comment: When I using that I have faced an issue that's why I decided to design my own using mat-buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925724/how-to-customize-angular-material-design-stepper-in-angular-4

Comment: Maybe look for material dividers ? https://material.angular.io/components/divider/overview

There's a few ones that you could look for

Answer (score 1):

You can use :after psuedo class

```css
.divider:after {
  height:1px;
  width:40px;
  content:'';
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">      
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="container" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
      <div class="row divided">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button mat-mini-fab>1</button>
          <span style="padding-left:0px">Login</span>
          <span class="divider"></span>
        </div>            
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button mat-mini-fab>2</button>
          <span style="padding-left:0px">Address</span>
          <span class="divider"></span>
        </div>            
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button mat-mini-fab>3</button>
          <span style="padding-left:0px">Mycart</span>
          <span class="divider"></span>
        </div>            
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button mat-mini-fab>4</button>
          <span style="padding-left:0px">Payment</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code adds equally sized lines between menu items as long there is enough space.

```css
/* all direct children of menu and item are laid out in a single row as long as there is enough space */
.menu,
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

/* all menu items can grow except the last one */
.item:not(:last-child) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* a horizontal line is appended to all items if space is available (except the last item) */
.item:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50%;  /* centers line vertically */
  flex-grow: 1; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* not relevant for menu (typography and resets) */
button,
span {
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* not relevant for menu (rounded buttons) */
button {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="item">
        <button>1</button>
        <span>Login</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <button>2</button>
        <span>Address</span>
    </div>   
    <div class="item">
        <button>3</button>
        <span>Mycart</span>
    </div>      
    <div class="item">
        <button>4</button>
        <span>Payment</span>
    </div>     
</div>
```

A

Comment: if you use an item class inside a menu class, you might use ul and li instead divs ;) (boostrap was used here, you may also want to add a row class to menu)

Comment: @G-Cyr You are right, using ul and li would be more semantic. At the beginning I started to create a Bootstrap 4 solution until I have realized that the main points would be obscured by CSS resets. I think the best way to follow is a minimalistic approach without Bootstrap at all.